# react-i18next not loading json translation files in React app created with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, i18next, react-i18next

I've created a React application with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

I want to implement translations and I've discovered [react-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next)

After installing required packages I've setup my i18n.js config file:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';

i18n
    .use(XHR)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .init({
      debug: true,
      lng: 'en',
      nsSeparator: false,
      keySeparator: false,
      fallbackLng: false,
      backend: {
        loadPath: 'locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
      }
    });


export default i18n;
```

I'm getting this error: `i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language en failed failed parsing locales/en/translation.json to json`

It happens because webpack doesn't find the json file and is returning the index.html file contents instead:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure where you put the locale files, but I see two issues:

1. You have specified a relative URL so you load `/kiosk/parents/locales` rather than `/locales`. You need to add a slash at the beginning of the load path.
2. For Create React App to serve static files, you need to put them into the `public` folder. This is described in its User Guide in more detail. So make sure `locales` is inside the `public` folder in the project root.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

Just in case anyone needs this like I did:

If you happen to have changed your homepage path in your package.json file like so:

```
...
    "homepage": "/tom/",
...
```

you also need to add this part to i18n like so:

```
i18n
    .use(XHR)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .init({
      debug: true,
      lng: 'en',
      nsSeparator: false,
      keySeparator: false,
      fallbackLng: false,
      backend: {
        loadPath: '/tom/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
      }
    });


export default i18n;
```

Comment: Jesus... that was convoluted, I lost an hour of my life and I couldn't find an answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: What should I do if I am using a proxy?