# Google Cloud: react-i18next not loading json translation files in React app

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, create-react-app, react-i18next

I have the same problem as described here ([stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898155/react-i18next-not-loading-json-translation-files-in-react-app-created-with-creat)) except I have both of my items configured properly.

my i18n.js configuration is setup as follows.

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import { reactI18nextModule } from 'react-i18next';

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(reactI18nextModule)
  .init({
        interpolation: {
            // React already does escaping
            escapeValue: false
        },
        lng: 'en',
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      backend: {
        loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json',
        allowMultiLoading: true
      },
      debug: true,
      react: {
        wait: true
      }
  });

export default i18n;
```

I'm getting this error `i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language en failed failed parsing locales/en/translation.json to json`

I made sure that my `locales` directory is in my `public` directory. I also verified that post `npm run build` the `locales` directory is copied over to the `build` directory.

In my staging environment I open the Network tab on Chrome Dev Tools and open `translations.json` in a new tab. I am taken to the correct url `https://example.com/locales/en/translation.json` however I am redirected to my index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App Engine Standard, you require a handler in your app.yaml configuration file that associate an URL pattern to the static files uploaded. You would use regex to define the extension files that would be considered as static file in the path specified for static files.

eg. from [app.yaml configuration for static files in App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers).

`handlers:
 - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
   static_files: static/\1
   upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$`

where,

url = URL pattern that will be treated as paths to static files.
static_files = path of the static files.
upload = regex that matches the file paths for all files that will be referenced by this handler when deploying the application.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the part that I was missing is that I am deploying to Google Cloud and the configuration for that requires me to specify what filetypes are allowed to be used as static resources. I added `json` to my configuration and now it works.

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(html|css|js|png|jpg|woff|json))
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/(.*\.(html|css|js|png|jpg|woff|json))
```