# i18n inserts JSON access strings (keys in the translation file) instead of values

Tags: json, networking, browser, react-i18next, public-folders

As opposed to [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898155/react-i18next-not-loading-json-translation-files-in-react-app-created-with-creat) my app finds the translation files when working with `i18n` in React. My issue is that for English & Romanian I get the JSON key (the access string) instead of the translations.

What happens is: only the German language works when selected. Also, for some reason, the german `translation.json` is displayed with different colors in the Preview (network tab) of Chrome's inspect console than the other languages (Romanian & English); nonetheless, these seem to be found, too (as shown in the network tab). Due to the different way Preview shows these, I am guessing this is an access problem? (check photos)

Below is how I my site looks when selecting English vs selecting German and also how I initialized i18n & how I am using it in my app, together with the json files.

Issue:
[image]

Code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I apologize! The issue was indeed with the JSON files, but not with the manner of accessing them. The problem was a few trailing commas. This is also the reason why Preview showed them differently in Chrome's inspect console.